# How to solve the error: invalid conversion from " int* " to " int "

Tags: c++, int

Need some help with the problem.
When I compile my code below, it gives me this error:

> error: invalid conversion from " `int*` " to " `int` "

I want to create a `calculatePercentage` function, so I can use the value when I call it.

```
void calculatePercentage(int voteResult[],int percentage[])

const int NO_OF_CANDIDATE = 10;

int main()
    {     
        ifstream input("votes.txt",ios::in);

        string candidates[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE];
        int    voteResult[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE]; 
        int    percentage[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE];   

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; i++) {
            input >> candidates[i] >> voteResult[i];  
        } 
        calculatePercentage(voteResult, percentage); // error happened here.

        return 0;
    }

void calculatePercentage(int voteResult[],int percentage[])
{
    int totalVotes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; i++) 
        {
            totalVotes += votes[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; j++) 
        {
            double wk_percentage  = static_cast<double>{votes[j])/totalVotes;
            percentage[j]=static_cast<int>(wk_percentage*100);
        }

}
```

Comment: You have an unmatched bracket: `static_cast<double>{`

Comment: `(100 * votes[j]) / totalVotes` get rid of all those cast.

Comment: Is `NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE` suppose to be `NO_OF_CANDIDATE `? is `votes[i]` suppose to be `voteResult[i]`? Compiling this example produces errors other than the one the question asks about.

Comment: Too many transcription errors, and nothing here that would obviously cause the stated error. Present a [MCVE].

Comment: Once typos fixed, it seems to works [Demo](https://ideone.com/t4eYKk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has a bunch of errors.

1. calculatePercentage() definition is missing the closing ';'
2. probable name mismatch between NO_OF_CANDIDATE and NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE
3. missing #include <fstream>  (using ifstream)
4. missing #include <string>
5. missing std:: namespace before `ifstream` and `string`
6. `votes` not declared anywhere (should it be `voteResult`?)
7. wrong opening curly bracket instead in `static_cast<double>{votes[j])/totalVotes;`

...
Let alone the way you do calculation and parameter passing...

The following edited code should compile, not sure if it works as you expected:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void calculatePercentage(int voteResult[], int percentage[]);

const int NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE = 10;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("votes.txt");

    std::string candidates[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE];
    int    voteResult[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE]; 
    int    percentage[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE];   

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; i++) {
        input >> candidates[i] >> voteResult[i];  
    } 
    calculatePercentage(voteResult, percentage); // error happened here.

    return 0;
}

void calculatePercentage(int voteResult[], int percentage[])
{
    int totalVotes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; i++) 
    {
        totalVotes += voteResult[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; j++) 
    {
        double wk_percentage  = static_cast<double>(voteResult[j]) / totalVotes;
        percentage[j] = static_cast<int>(wk_percentage*100);
    }
}
```

Also on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/yxecI9).

Comment: I can run it with your comment. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone's comment. I skipped some statements and made some typos when posting them.  I fixed them as follows. The only error occurred is that still cannot convert " int* " from " int". Just don't know how to solve it.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void calculatePercentage(int voteResult[],int percentage[]);

const int NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE = 10;

int main()
    {     
        ifstream input("votes.txt",ios::in);


        string candidates[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE];
        int    vote[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE]; 
        int    percentage[NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE];   

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; i++) {
            input >> candidates[i] >> vote[i];  
        } 
        calculatePercentage(voteResult, percentage); // error happened here.

        return 0;
    }

void calculatePercentage(int voteResult[],int percentage[])
{
    int totalVotes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; i++) 
        {
            totalVotes += votes[i];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_CANDIDATE; j++) 
        {
            double wk_percentage  = static_cast<double>(votes[j])/totalVotes;
            percentage[j]=static_cast<int>(wk_percentage*100);
        }

}
```

Comment: You did a "typo": `voteResult` should be `vote`.You should have previous error similar to "use of undeclared identifier 'voteResult' (it happen that compiler may use `int` type to unknown variable to allow to provide more error in the file, and so the incompatible type). Look at the full build log and not only to the "resume error part".

Comment: BTW, That is not an answer, You should instead edit your post (but care to not invalidate existing answers).